# jQuery Created Nested Table Based on Attribute

Tags: jquery, html-table, nested

So I asked a very similar question yesterday about nested lists thinking that I would be able to use the answer both for creating nested lists and nested tables. But when I try to modify the jQuery to created nested tables it goes a little haywire. Either it doesn't nest or it nests an entire table with the child `<tr>`'s under the parent `<tr>` instead of just the child `<tr>`'s. Sample tables:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="10"><td>Parent 1</td></tr>
        <tr id="14"><td>Parent 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="10"><td>Child A</td></tr>
        <tr class="10"><td>Child B</td></tr>
        <tr Class="14"><td>Child X</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

(This jQuery is based on code that vzwick very graciously helped me with) The jQuery looks like this:

```
$('tbody.csTR_children tr').each(function() {
        probable_parent = $('tbody.csTR_parent tr#' + $(this).attr('class'));
        if (probable_parent.length) {
            if (!probable_parent.find('tbody').length) probable_parent.append('<tbody/>');
        $(this).detach().appendTo(probable_parent.find('tbody'));
    }
});
```

This is the closest I get and it nests an entire table under each parent row (in IE it nests the first parent and child properly but the rest it doesn't), as I said above. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('tbody.csTR_children tr').each(function() {
    probable_parent = $('#' + $(this).data('parentID'));
    if (probable_parent.length) {
        if (!probable_parent.find('tbody').length)
        $(this).detach().insertAfter(probable_parent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to append a `tbody` to a `tr` which is just completely wrong.  A `tbody` must be directly within a `table` and you can't put that table directly in the `tr`, it has to be in a `td`

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDUQU/

So basically, append a table to the first `td` in the row:

```
probable_parent.children(":first").append('<table><tbody></tbody></table>');
```

Comment: Thank you. It works nicely but I ran into a little problem...if I add any more td's to the parent (or child), it breaks.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me:  http://jsfiddle.net/ZDUQU/1/  can you update the fiddle and post it broken?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was if I add td's to the existing tr's [jsfiddle.net/h6y5a/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/h6y5a/2/). If I replace your last line of code with `$(this).detach().appendTo(probable_parent.next('table').find('tbody'));` it gets closer but not quite there.

Comment: Then you need to give some indication of which td is the "parent".  Try this:  http://jsfiddle.net/h6y5a/3/

Comment: Ideally the entire row is the parent. I just want them stacked one on top of another. Am I chasing something that's not possible? http://jsfiddle.net/h6y5a/4/

Comment: I think I know what you mean and you can do it, it's just more complicated.  You won't be able to just copy the whole row, you'll need to copy each cell.  Do you not have access to the backend? It would be easier for you to just spit it out the right way and not have to edit it on the front end.

Comment: Just to clarify, I want a parent row with child rows underneath it with the cells exactly aligned. I think we're on the same page. So what's on the backend is two databases that I'm querying with CAML and generating two tables as discussed above. Then I'm trying to combine the tables. If I can produce the nested table right off the bat that would be great.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance up til now but I've figured it out. +1 for getting me half way there.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. I think it does what you want:

```
$('table#child tr').each(function() {
    var parentId = $(this).data('parentId');
    var parent = $('#' + parentId);
    if (parent) {
        var tbody = $('tbody', parent);
        if (tbody.length == 0) {
            // need to add the table wrapper
            tbody = $('<tbody>');
            var table = $('<table>').append(tbody);
            parent.append(table);
        }
        $(this).detach().appendTo(tbody);
    }
});
```

Here is a jsFiddle for you to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/78aXx/2/

Bob

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If you look at the jsFiddle, though, it's putting child tables under each tr. I would like the child tr's directly under the parent.

Comment: `parent` is a `tr` so you can't append a table to it.